# How to configure micromax 352g modem in  12.04

Tags: 12.04, internet-connection, modem

I am using Micromax 352g modem for Internet purpose and using TATA DOCOMO sim in it.
The problem that I am facing right now is not able to access Internet in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with my modem.

I have tried almost all tricks but failed to succeed.
Please help me out.

Comment: Please explain the operating characteristics, especially the computer-to-modem communication characteristics in use with this modem.

Answer (score 0):

## Try Betavine Connection Manager

It's from vodafone, and works for a wide range of mobile broadbands

https://forge.betavine.net/frs/?group_id=76&release_id=285